# What is the lifespan of a series of currency?

Tags: financial-literacy, currency

I traveled to Canada from the USA and as a souvenir I decided to bring some Canadian cash back with me. While I plan to keep it just as a souvenir, it made me wonder how long a currency can legally be used? For example, if I tried to use currency from the early 20th century today I doubt most businesses would accept it. Does anyone have an average timeframe before currency is "obsolete"?

Comment: In short it is unpredictable. For developed nations there is less possibility of events that would make old currencies obsolete. For other countries the possibilities are more.

Answer (score 3):

In general, currency has no expiration date.

Specifically, in Canada, the Bank of Canada has been issuing banknotes since 1935, and these are [still considered legal tender](http://www.bankofcanada.ca/banknotes/bank-notes-faq/), even though they don't look much like the modern banknotes.  Before that, [Canadian chartered banks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_chartered_bank_notes) issued currency, and these also still have value.

However, there are a few things to note.  First of all, with currency of that age, it often has more value as a collector's item than the face value.  So spending it at a store would be foolish.

Second, store clerks are not experts in old currency, and will not accept a bill that they do not recognize.  If you want the face value of your old currency, you may need to exchange it for modern currency at a bank.

Having said all that, there are certainly cases where currency does expire.  Generally this happens when a country changes currency.  For example, when the Euro was introduced, the old currencies were discontinued.  After a window of exchange, the old currency in many cases lost its value.  So if you have some old French Franc notes, for example, they can [no longer be exchanged for Euros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_franc#Euro_exchange).

These types of events cannot be predicted in the future, of course, so it is impossible to say when, if ever, the Canadian currency you have today will lose its spending value in Canada.

Comment: Apart from Euro, Inflation has meant that quite a few countries like Brazil, Argentina, etc have re-denominated the currencies. As part of security upgrades to currencies quite a few countries have made old series obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

US currency doesn't expire, it is always legal tender.

I can see some trouble if you tried to spend a $10,000 bill (you'd be foolish to do so, since they are worth considerably more). Maybe some stores raise eyebrows at old-style $100's (many stores don't take $100 bills at all), but you could swap them for new style at a bank if having trouble with a particular store.

Old-series currency can be an issue when trying to exchange US bills in other countries, just because it doesn't expire here, doesn't mean you can't run into issues elsewhere.

Other countries have different policies, for example, over the last year the UK phased in a new five pound note, and as of last month (5/5/2017) the old fiver is no longer considered legal tender (can still swap out old fivers at the bank for now at least).

Edit: I mistook which currency you took where, and focused on US currency instead of Canadian, but it looks like it's the same story there.

Comment: There is some older US Money that said it was convertible to Silver or Gold.   While the bill is still valid for exchange to a new bill, it can no longer  be exchanged for actual Gold or Silver.

Answer (score -3):

Currency lives no more then 50 years.
US currency did not expire in last 100 years, but it was reinstated few times, last one was 2009.

Note that currency is *not* just what you hold in your hand. Currency is system of relations of money supply (currency is not money but we forced to use standard terminology), banking rules and government policy. Currency exists as long as government wants it to.

In 2009 for example, US government decided it needs new currency and just printed whole new money supply. So US dollar is now counting as "partially fresh new currency". It was reinstated. Not expired. But today's dollar is totally different from 90s and 00s. Will it be accepted after 200 years? Yes (probably). But *most likely* at that time there will be totally new US dollars. And new Euros, new Pounds and so on.

*Currency is method of transfer*. You can have that physical coins you have, but as economic agent it will die very quickly. It is not only related to inflation, in fact, inflation is the least of your worries. If you count all currencies in the world which ever existed, most of them 99.99% are completely dead by now (with governments which supported it). Not even single one currency which lived more then 100 years. US dollar was reinstated in 1860, 1907, 1930, 1973, 1987, 2009 and  in fact it is *not* single currency but dozen which were allowed to be used "for compatibility reasons".

Comment: Have any citations for this?

Comment: I have coins from different countries, my wife likes to collect them. Most of old coins minted in 60s are dead.

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean by "Currency lives."  You said that it lives no more than 50 years, and then say that U.S. currency hasn't expired in the last 100 years.  And what do you mean by "reinstated"?

Comment: US dollars today are all printed in 2009, it means that pre-2009 dollars are depopulated. It is reinstate of currency. No expire, but it is entirely new money supply.

Comment: @sanaris So I should just shred the dollar bill I have in my hand that's dated 2001?

Comment: No, but you taking it too seriously. Currency is not something you could save with and will never be.

Comment: New money supply -> new currency. You cannot have same currency if all what you have in your pocket is 1860s greenbacks. Even if those greenbacks are still considered equal to other paper notes.

Comment: I think you're raising an interesting point that there's a difference between currency, and physical notes and coins and that a currency can exist over time while the value representations of notes and coins may change over time.  But I think you need to refine what point you're making.

Comment: @sanaris The question is "how long will the paper note I kept as a souvenir be valid".  You seem to be providing broad generalizations on the average life of the money in circulation, which does not answer the question. A paper dollar that was printed well before 2009 is still valid currency.  The fact that the mint will probably "recycle" it is not relevant.

Comment: It is not about "recycle", new governments accept new policies and drop old currencies. 50 years is a very long livespan for currency. Average currency lasts about 30-40 years.

Comment: Why talk about "average" when we're talking about Canada, @sanaris? Canadian notes have not been de-monetized since they were first issued 80 years ago.

Comment: Listen, guys. With all 99.99% of finance industry is making you believe in something, I am telling you how EXACTLY it works inside. If your "world picture" does not correlate, move on and pay your money to financial "advisors" who will teach you the best ways to loosing your savings. Finally, if not 99% of people were loosers, where would billionaires and governments make their toll?

Comment: @Beanluc and other example, russian ruble in 1992, it was whole new currency with government backing it, then in 1998 it defaulted government bonds (together with asian markets default). After that chaotic devaluation, ruble lost 70% of buying power. Government decided to cut 3 zeros, to make people believing in currency again. Old currency has died successfully and new currency was born under same name  (but bills were all new). Overall livespan esimated: under 7 years.